# Django: ORM Design Issue

Tags: python, django, orm

**Scenario:**  Vehicle Testing - (Vehicles are booked into a test cell and then tested)

For example purposes I have created two simplified models:

```py
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    registration = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    tyre_pressure = models.IntegerField()

class Booking(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES= (('Booked','Booked'),('Complete','Complete'))

    booking_datetime = models.DatetimeField(auto_now=True)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

When a booking is created/booked, it creates a `Booking` object with the status **Booked** and the booking has an assigned vehicle.

Once the test has completed, the `Booking` object changes it's status to **Complete**. The vehicle is now vacant for the next test.

**Issue**

The `tyre_pressure` for the vehicle (*for example*) may change later on after the Booking completed (Maybe for a different test) and cause the test to have incorrect data for that particular time.

I want the Booking record to reflect the vehicle state at that particular time of the booking rather than the present value.

**What I've considered**

- When a vehicle is edited/updated it creates a new, unique id. This would conflict with the `unique=True` parameter in the `registration` field.
- Include all vehicle fields inside `Booking` Model for given test instead of `Vehicle` object.
- Possibly create a new `VehicleConfiguration` model. Contains all properties except the unique key. New record is created on every change to vehicle and historical changes are stored with date changed. Like so:

```py
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    registration = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    vehicle_config = models.ForeignKey(VehicleConfiguration, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

class VehicleConfig(models.Model):
    tyre_pressure = models.IntegerField()
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common pattern, where you need a frozen state of a changeable model at a certain point in time. There's various ways to deal with it. In e-commerce, you see this pattern when a Product in a catalogue is purchased, it cannot be a foreign key in the Order, but a copy needs to be made with the price of that time, even the name at that time. The Order references PurchasedItem instead of Product and they share a number of fields.

However, in this case you may be able to separate test data from vehicle:

```py
class Booking(models.Model):
     vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, related_name='bookings')
     test_results = models.ForeignKey('Test', null=True)  # ManyToMany if one booking can result in multiple tests
     ... financial data

class Vehicle(models.Model):
     ... static vehicle data, like make, license plate, owner, etc

class Test(models.Model):
    test_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tyre_pressure = models.IntegerField()
```

So in this case, the booking ties the vehicle and test together and test is assumed to be static. The vehicle's tyre pressure, would be a proxy method to the latest test:

```py
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def tyre_pressure(self) -> int:
        return self.bookings.filter(
            status='completed', test__isnull=False
        ).latest('test__test_time').tyre_pressure
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer thankyou. Would you happen to recommend any further readings on common patterns such as this?

Comment: Aside from the [data modelling books](https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/data-modeling), I would highly recommend [Two scoops of Django](https://www.pydanny.com/two-scoops-of-django-3-x.html) if you're going to stick with Django.

Comment: If I require to update the tyre pressure without the need for a test. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an abstract model for vehicle and booking to inherit shared properties from. Pretty much your second bullet point idea.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the answer. Although this does the job, I feel if the vehicles parameters haven't changes for 20+ tests. I would be replicating data and not making efficient use of the database. Any opinion on the new consideration?